# How to recover or recreate orginal Postgres database after dropping it?

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally dropped original postgres database after installing postgreSQL software. Postgres user is still there, \du superuser. How to recover or recreate original postgres database?

Comment: Restore your backup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html

just run

```
create database postgres;
```

it will create db with default template (which is "template1"). If you did not modify it - it will be same is previous "postgres" db

Answer (score -1):

You can only recover it if you have some previous backup of that database, by restoring that backup and then applying WAL files upto the time when drop database statement was issued.

There is no other way to recover a dropped database.

Comment: This is incorrect, the original default database can be recreated.