# how to restore database 'postgres' from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using local postgresql and pgadmin 4. I dropped database 'postgres' and now pgadmin won't open. How can I restore 'postgres' or fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover or recreate orginal Postgres database after dropping it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812178/how-to-recover-or-recreate-orginal-postgres-database-after-dropping-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the definition of the "server" in pgAdmin and set the "maintenance database" to something else than `postgres`, for example `template1`.

Then you will be able to connect, and you can create the database `postgres` again.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful.