# Postgres error message (in pgAdmin): "database 'postgres' does not exist", after 'postgres' table droped

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

In order to organize my local database server, I've executed `DROP DATABASE postgres;`. After it when I try to connect to database, it shows an error message:

> database "postgres" does not exist

I've restarted the service; I've tried to reinstall postgres (install file:'postgresql-12.11-1-windows-x64'); I've tried to change the 'method' of file 'pg_hba.conf', from 'md5' to 'trust'. But the error continues.

Please, how can I create this 'postgres' database? Or other solution?

Comment: Why do you expect you can connect to a database named `postgres` after you dropped it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover or recreate orginal Postgres database after dropping it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812178/how-to-recover-or-recreate-orginal-postgres-database-after-dropping-it)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new server and then a new database. When I was recreating a database, I identified that the database 'postgres' is automacally created, and to create a my database is necessary set a owner, and by default the owner is 'postgres'.

Note: Maybe this suggestion ([How to recover or recreate orginal Postgres database after dropping it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812178/how-to-recover-or-recreate-orginal-postgres-database-after-dropping-it)) could be work, when I saw this reply I'd already soluted how I described above.